# How can I initialize a database table with Flask / SQLalchemy / Alembic?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, data-migration, alembic

I have a database table of languages with relatively static content:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Language(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'languages'

    # Fields
    code = db.Column(db.String(2), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    native = db.Column(db.String(60))
    rtl = db.Column(db.Boolean())  # right to left
```

The [data is in a CSV](https://github.com/MartinThoma/mpu/blob/master/mpu/data/laguages.csv.gz). I want to insert it into the database. Can I do this with alembic?

I initialize all tables (the structure, not the data) with

```
$ flask db init
$ flask db migrate
$ flask db update
```

(Side-question: Should this be in the database in the first place, or maybe rather as a CSV in the code? I use it in a CMS to allow users to specify which languages the speak / which language the page is they've created.)

### My Try

Providing an endpoint which adds the stuff when called:

```
@app.route('/secret_init_languages')
def db_init_languages():
    from mpu.string import str2bool
    import csv
    path = resource_filename('my_package', 'static/languages.csv')
    nb_languages = 0
    with open(path, 'rt', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next(csvreader, None)  # skip the headers
        for row in csvreader:
            lang = Language(code=row[0],
                            name=row[1],
                            native=row[2],
                            rtl=str2bool(row[3]))
            db.session.add(lang)
            nb_languages += 1
        db.session.commit()
    return 'Added {} languages'.format(nb_languages)
```

Drawbacks of this solution:

- I have an endpoint which should only be called once
- I could forget to run it

Comment: alembic is not a data migration tool, primarily. You can use flask-migrate to update the database with the correct tables, but you'll need to move the data over yourself. `db = SQLAlchemy()` and `class Language(db.Model):` don't make sense to me unless you're also using flask-sqlalchemy

Comment: I don't think `db = SQLAlchemy()` will be registered on the app

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, I do use flask-sqlalchemy. For this reason I added the tag. And I do `db.init_app(app)`, of course.

Comment: @roganjosh What is the data migration tool of choice then? (I have a MySQL-DB)

Comment: Well, that invalidated the answer I'm mid-way through typing.  Now I don't know what you're asking

Comment: Data migration from CSV to your database is probably a manual job once the schema is set

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have resolved this yet, I've had a similar problem initializing a database table with a csv using Flask and SQLAlchemy. The following solution worked for me (not using alembic):

```
from main.app import app
from main.db import db
from models.table import TableModel
from pandas import read_csv

db.init_app(app)

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()
    # Check if the existing table contain data, if not then initialize with csv insert
    s = db.session()
    if len(s.query(TableModel).all()) == 0:
        print('No data in the table detected.')
        print('Initialising the table in database.')
        engine = s.get_bind()
        df = read_csv('./table.csv')
        df.to_sql('table',
                  con=engine,
                  if_exists='append',
                  chunksize=1000,
                  index=False)

app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Note the code above is contained in a `run.py` script, which calls the flask app object and the SQLAlchemy object (from flask-sqlalchemy) from the main.app and main.db modules respectively. `TableModel` is the class mapping to the desired table in the database. I used the `@app.before_first_request` decorator together with `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` method so that the initialization of the database (including insertion of data from csv) will only be performed once when the app fires up initially. I'm not sure if `alembic` is a requirement for you though, but `pandas` did work for me and I hope this helps.